# trying to disable windows task wake computer, get task scheduler service not available

Tags: windows-8, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

This is a windows 8.1 pc upgraded from 8.0

I've been trying to stop my PC from waking up on it's own. Turns out there are some windows update tasks that are set to wake the pc to run the task (whoever made that decision at MS should be flogged).

When i try to turn off the option to allow the task to wake the PC i get the error that the task scheduler service is not available.

Pretty sure it is available since it's running in the services and i can restart it. Plus I can change the properties on other tasks. So i'm guessing this is some sort of permission issue trying to prevent me from making changes to the windows update tasks. Although if that is the case, it's a pretty weak security measure since I can disable those tasks without any problem.

Can anyone tell me how to edit this task to prevent it from waking my PC?

Comment: For reference: Following these instructions on disabling the auto-wake (http://superuser.com/a/973029/243710) led me to encounter the problem you describe here.  I might guess the issue is connected to changing permissions on the Update task, don't know yet.