# PC turn on automatically at intermittent time

Tags: windows-10, power-management

After I turn off my computer (or hibernate specifically) It turn on automatically. It seem not to happen regularly. (Or I think so).

I tried to disable all scheduled tasks with "Autoruns" program, but it doesn't seem to help.

And another thing - I had this problem on my older computer and then I basically "bought" new one, new windows etc. and it started again.  (Windows 10 on both, but not sure. might be earlier version also)

Can you help me troubleshoot it?

Comment: Do you have a WOL by any chance?

Comment: Have you unchecked  'Wake computer to run this' , maintenance can also be in security program to run when needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conclusively stop wake timers from waking Windows 10 desktop](http://superuser.com/questions/973009/conclusively-stop-wake-timers-from-waking-windows-10-desktop)

Comment: Make sure none of your tasks have the "Allow this task to wake the computer to run" option enabled. Checking the Task Scheduler logs will help you determine when something was last run, and you can see if that aligns with when your PC is turning on. Also, you can check in the BIOS and make sure that the PC does not automatically turn on after power failure.