# Is there a global setting to enable/disable all devices from waking the computer?

Tags: windows-10, sleep

I have discovered a newly installed device preventing a power transition (namely, sleep) from taking place on my computer. I would not like to have to manually disallow all devices from causing my computer to wake. Is there a way to globally disable all devices and their drivers from preventing sleep in Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to use the command prompt to find what devices have the ability to wake the computer.

Run the command prompt as an administrator and type in `powercfg devicequery wake_armed`.  This will report back a list of the devices with the ability to wake your computer.

You can disable the devices by typing in `powercfg devicedisablewake "deviceNameFromList"`.  Use the up and down arrow keys to cycle through the commands to make this faster.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Moreover, the wake-requesting device is not visible under `wake_armed` (it is actually visible only  under `wake_from_any`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of one, no.

However, this program makes it very easy to enable/disable the waking for individual devices: https://superuser.com/a/1147093/231129