# Peripherals wake Windows 10 from sleep mode despite being explicitly prohbited from doing so in device manager

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, sleep

I have been attempting to overcome sleep issues with my windows 10 (build 10586.494) Surface 3. I recently followed and implemented [Seagulls' excellent walkthrough for eliminating unwanted windows wake-ups](https://superuser.com/questions/973009/conclusively-stop-wake-timers-from-waking-windows-10-desktop), but noticed that unchecking the 'Allow this device to wake the computer' through device manager doesn't actually stop the device from waking the computer. The Typecover keyboard that I'm using is still able to wake my device despite all keyboard drivers having their 'allow this device to wake the computer' box unchecked. The same applies to the Typecover touchpad driver (box unchecked, but still able to wake the device).

I think that the Typecover keyboard is waking the Surface 3 up in my bag when a key on it is accidently pressed, causing the battery on the device to drain.

If anyone has experienced this problem and has a solution, please let me know!