# My computer wakes itself after approx. 45 sec

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power-management, wake-up

I have search this forum for answers and tried to solve by solutions suggested in diffrent answers but problem still remains.
I am running a windows 10 64 bit system.

My computer wakes up after just 45 seconds in sleep.

```
powercfg -lastwake (Wake History Count - 1 Wake History [0] Wake Source Count - 0)
Event viewer shows 
"The system has returned from a low power state.
Sleep Time: ‎2017‎-‎03‎-‎24T10:51:53.691825600Z
Wake Time: ‎2017‎-‎03‎-‎24T10:52:59.141104700Z
Wake Source: Unknown"
```

**Things I tried:**

- powercfg -devicequery wake_armed → NONE
- powercfg -waketimers → There
  are no active wake timers in the system.
- Power Options Advanced
  Settings → Sleep → Allow wake timers → Disable (on all power plans)
- Control Panel / System and Security / Security and Maintenance / Automatic Maintenance → "Allow scheduled maintenance to wake up my computer at the scheduled time" unchecked.
- All wake on "Magic Packet" of all network adapters are set to "Disabled" in the Advanced settings of the devices in Device Manager.
- Get-ScheduledTask | where {$_.settings.waketorun} returns nothing
  I have disabled and change the "Reboot" task under UpdateOrchestrator according to this [guide](https://superuser.com/a/973029/226996)

Now i am out of options...please help!

Comment: Not sure if any of the answers / suggestions on this Q might help - https://superuser.com/questions/973009/conclusively-stop-wake-timers-from-waking-windows-10-desktop?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Intel has software, Intel Active Management Technology, that operates even when the PC is completely shut down that *might* be causing loss of sleep (for you and the PC). You might try disabling these services to see if it helps. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Active_Management_Technology