# PC wakes itself up in Hibernate

Tags: windows-7, sleep, hibernate

I recently bought a HP EliteDesk 800 G1. 4th gen i5. PC works well. I use Hibernate instead of Power Off, as on all my PC/Laptops. The PC is permanently connected to power, the screens power is turned off.

After I hibernate the PC I normally go to bed. The PC is in Hibernate as the power LED is not there anymore. In the morning I find the PC in running state. No data has been lost as the programs before hibernate are all open.

Why did the PC start by itself? I checked BIOS, there is no wakeup on specific Time (all days are disabled). There is no Wake on Lan used, but still the PC powers up by itself.

Does anybody know why or could point me where to look?

Windows 8.1, 8 GB RAM, SSD, second HDD. Windows updates are manually, as on all my PCs.

Comment: Open an administrator command prompt and type the following command: c:\powercfg -lastwake     ...what does the output say?

Comment: Also do a `powercfg /systempowerreport`, open the report and check out how long the PC was in hibernation. If it's 6 hours and about 28 seconds in duration you have the same problem as here: https://superuser.com/questions/1262733/after-upgrade-to-fall-creators-update-computer-wakes-after-6-hours-28-minutes-w (no solution yet, although I thought it was specific to Win10)

Comment: powercfg -lastwake tells me "Wake History Cout - 1, Wake History [0], Wake Source Count - 0"

Comment: Systempowerreport is an invalid parameter - does not exist in powercfg /? either