# How Do I Install/Run NSudo?

Tags: windows, windows-10, sudo

This question should be viewed as a related question from the following
question on Super User; "Disable UpdateOrchestrator Reboot task", which can be viewed at the following link:

[Disable UpdateOrchestrator Reboot task](https://superuser.com/questions/1268789/disable-updateorchestrator-reboot-task#new-answer?newreg=4fbe56b535c64029b42c060309f02d06)

The above link proposes downloading software called "NSudo", in which it purportedly fixed all of the problems that the author was having in regards to their computer waking from sleep due to the Reboot Task not allowing them to turn off that task's function of waking the computer from sleep.

However, within the installation instructions of NSudo, which are originally written in Japanese characters; the ReadMe file lists that a .bat file is to be run in order to facilitate proper installation of NSudo.

However, based on my findings, no such .bat file exists within the scope of the provided NSudo sourcefiles page.

Below are screenshots of the sourcefiles included on the github source page for NSudo:

---

Parent Directory

[image]

---

NSudo / Nsudo.Icon /

[image]

---

NSudo / NSudo /

[image]

---

NSudo / NSudo / res /

[image]

---

NSudo / NSudoSDK /

[image]

---

NSudo / NSudoSDK / Third Party /

[image]

If anyone could help me out that would be appreciated!

Comment: I'd think that it would be better to add the [Link to NSudo's GitHub-Page](https://github.com/M2Team/NSudo) than to add screenshots of the same. Also, the simple solution is: [Go to the "release"-site](https://github.com/M2Team/NSudo/releases). The not-so simple solution is: compile it yourself from the source.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the source code! Go [here](https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/nsudo-a-powerful-system-administration-tool.59268/) for the link to download the actual thing (including the .bat or .exe file).