# What is the command line equivalent for toggling "wake the computer to run this task"?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-task-scheduler, wake-up

From a sufficiently elevated command prompt I can disable any task from running at all e.g. with

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>schtasks /Change /Disable /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot"
SUCCESS: The parameters of scheduled task "\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot" have been changed.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>whoami
nt authority\system
```

But how can I toggle just the "wake the computer to run this task" bit, as it's called in the GUI Task Scheduler, but *from the command line*? I've looked through the help page of `schtasks /change /?` but I can't see the equivalent for toggling that "wake the computer" bit. So is there a way of toggling that using `schtasks` or some other command line utility (preferably built-in)?

[image]

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497945/using-schtasks-from-the-command-line-what-parameter-will-wake-the-computer-from) one can export the task description to XML, delete it (this step is actually necessary--otherwise you get `ERROR: Cannot create a file when that file already exists`), edit the XML description to remove just the offending bit, and then recreate/import it. Both of these (export-to-xml, and import-from-xml) can be done just with `schtasks`...  I can confirm that this works:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>schtasks /query /xml /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot" > C:\tools\reboot-task.xml

C:\WINDOWS\system32>schtasks /delete /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot"
WARNING: Are you sure you want to remove the task "\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot" (Y/N)? Y
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot" was successfully deleted.

REM edit the file C:\tools\reboot-task.xml and change <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>

C:\WINDOWS\system32>schtasks /create /xml C:\tools\reboot-task.xml /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot"
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot" has successfully been created.
```

Note that to be able to create tasks that will run as SYSTEM, you need to be SYSTEM, i.e. run from that from a properly elevated prompt (merely run-as-administrator will not work). Result:

[image]

But is there a simpler way, still from the command line?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/385431/add-a-new-scheduled-task-from-command-line-with-wake-the-computer-to-run-this-t and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497945/using-schtasks-from-the-command-line-what-parameter-will-wake-the-computer-from

Answer (score 2):

SCHTASKS cannot invoke Scheduler 2.0+ features and these include "Wake up machine to run this task".

If you want to do this from a command line you will need to use a Powershell cmdlet to set this.  You can still run Powershell cmdlets from a command prompt by using Powershell.exe . or by running a powershell script (.ps1)

Something like the following would do it:

```
$task=Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot"
$task.Settings.WakeToRun =$True
$task | Set-ScheduledTask -user "Username" -Password "Password"
```

Additional reference for these commands is here - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/get-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps
and https://ss64.com/ps/scheduler.html
and details on schtasks incompatibility here - https://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html

Comment: This almost worked. Unfortunately `Get-ScheduledTask` seems unable to access SYSTEM tasks, even if you run powershell as SYSTEM, which is pretty odd... `Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot"
Get-ScheduledTask : No MSFT_ScheduledTask objects found with property 'TaskPath' equal to
'\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot'.` Double checked that `PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> whoami
nt authority\system`

Comment: you need both a task path with leading and trailing slashes and a task name specified:

`PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\" -TaskName "Reboot"`

Answer (score 1):

The idea is good, but the syntax provided by elaverick is slightly incorrect; you need both a task path with leading and trailing slashes and a task name specified, e.g. (toggling it here in the opposite direction):

```
PS> $tsk = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\" -TaskName "Reboot"

PS> $tsk.Settings.WakeToRun
False

PS> $tsk.Settings.WakeToRun = $True

PS> $tsk | Set-ScheduledTask
```

The task description (class/object) contains the user (as `Principal`) so you don't really need to specify that unless you want a different one than what's saved in it when you `Get` the object.

```
PS> $tsk.Principal


DisplayName         :
GroupId             :
Id                  : Author
LogonType           : ServiceAccount
RunLevel            : Limited
UserId              : SYSTEM
ProcessTokenSidType : Default
RequiredPrivilege   :
PSComputerName      :
```

Actually `Get-ScheduledTask` implements some kind of (recursive, depth) search if you don't specify `TaskPath` but only specify `TaskName`. Note that the name *must not* contain the path though to trigger this search:

```
PS> Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Reboot"

TaskPath                                       TaskName                          State
--------                                       --------                          -----
\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\         Reboot                            Disabled
```

I'm not sure what happens if there are multiple tasks with the same name in various paths and you don't specify the path; I guess you get an array as that's what you get for no task name at all e.g. `Get-ScheduledTask | where {$_.Settings.WakeToRun}` is useful for finding all tasks that may wake up your computer.

Aside: beware that `Enable-ScheduledTask` (and its `Disable` opposite) don't have this depth-search behavior like `Get`, e.g. just

`Enable-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Reboot"`

fails, but

`Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Reboot" | Enable-ScheduledTask`

succeeds, as does

`Enable-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\" -TaskName "Reboot"`