# Windows "Schedule Wake To Work" scheduled tasks resume from sleep

Tags: windows, sleep, windows-task-scheduler

My PC is resuming from sleep because wake computer is enabled within scheduled task *Schedule Wake To Work*:

```
Timer set by [SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\svchost.exe (SystemEventsBroker) expires at 00:51:30 on 23/08/2023.
  Reason: Windows will execute 'NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Schedule Wake To Work' scheduled task that requested waking the computer.
```

- I've tried a lot of things reported in question [Disable UpdateOrchestrator Reboot task](https://superuser.com/questions/1268789/disable-updateorchestrator-reboot-task), but nothing works, and it keeps asking for the password of account `SYSTEM S-1-5-18`

How to disable this scheduled task or change the options?

Comment: Enable the option to run with highest credentials or else just delete the task

Comment: `SYSTEM` doesn't have a password, which is why the box @John mentioned needs to be checked _([example](https://i.imgur.com/RFOuUnA.png))_

Comment: John : this is what I did (Delete the task) and it worked out for me
THANKS !
Ps: I did not dare to do it, what this task is for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task Scheduler has an option in the General Tab to run with Highest Privileges .  This is a common setting.

Set the task to run with Highest Privileges .

In your case, the task was apparently trying to update something.

The other thing you can do is simply delete the Task.  Then it will not interfere with sleep.

Comment: At least on my system, it is not possible to delete the "Schedule wake to work" task, even when running the Task Scheduler as admin.  I assume it is created/owned with SYSTEM permissions.