# Multiple odd accounts in Windows 10 Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I've been trying to change settings in Task Scheduler following this post ([Conclusively stop wake timers from waking Windows 10 desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/973009/conclusively-stop-wake-timers-from-waking-windows-10-desktop)) but on making my setting Windows asks me for a password for one of these accounts. To be honest I recognize none of the accounts (I do recognize my mail but I actually use an offline account and pin to log in. What are these and are there default passwords I can try?

[image]

Comment: S-1-5-18 is a [special account used by the operating system](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I don't think it will have a password ...

Comment: Which change are you trying to make that requires a password? You should be logged in as an Administrator before making any of the changes.

Answer (score 8):

You won't be able to provide any password there as the user S-1-5-18 is a system account. [The PSExec tool from SysInternals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) can work around this issue by launching Task Scheduler as SYSTEM. Run this command in an elevated (admin) `cmd` prompt to launch Task Scheduler: `psexec -i -d -s mmc taskschd.msc`

Then proceed to modify the task as needed.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.