# Can Windows sleep in?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, sleep, wake-up

My Windows 10 Home laptop wakes up (I prefer sleep, instead of shutdown, when I am away from my
computer) a few times every day on its own though I disable "wake timers" and do my best to prevent
this.  The fan and hard disk often wake me up in the morning.  So, every few months,
I get frustrated and try again to fix this (e.g., I have tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/973009),
and have even called Microsoft and followed their advice), but never succeed.

So, is this normal?

I.e., if I buy a brand new Windows 10 Home laptop today and disable "wake timers", is it still likely to wake itself up more than 100 times over the next year?

EDIT: I am hoping that someone who has a few Windows 10 Home PCs using sleep
could testify that sleep works fine.  You can search for "Power-Troubleshooter"
in Event Viewer to see when you have woken.  My example snip is below (by the way,
the latest 11:05:36 was intentional, but the prior 08:20:10 was not; though
not in this snip, all show "Unknown" when I scroll to the "Wake Source" field).

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you completely followed the advice in the answers at the link you point to? In my experience it is more likely than not to be an unpredicted hardware wake setting that can be easily disabled using the method in step 4.

Comment: @shawn I wonder if you use Windows 10 Pro (not Home).  Anyway, I think I followed all steps (and honestly step #2, though I did it, shows that Windows is designed not to sleep in!).  As for step #4, I just checked again and "powercfg -devicequery wake_armed" response is "NONE".

Comment: really bad subject to say "sleep in",, state what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Step on will be figuring out what woke it up.  Run the following in a command window, or in PowerShell

> powercfg -lastwake

This will print out what triggered the wake event.  Should give you a clue where to start.

Looking at what is 'armed' will only show once the wake event is set.  It will not show when another service or task is planning to set one.  Perhaps if you ran it immediately before you put it to sleep it may show something.

In any case, once you identify what is waking it (most likely it is something that one of the steps in the process you were following will stop).

In one of my cases it was the dreaded UpdateOrchestrator.
In another it was 'wake on LAN', and the network was waking it up.
In another it was the darn cat bumping the mouse or walking on the keyboard at night giving a USB wake event...

Good Luck, G^2

Comment: I have checked "powercfg -lastwake" many times and it does not help (response is "Wake History Count - 1; Wake History [0]; Wake Source Count - 0").  Can you confirm that you have Windows 10 Home (Home edition is important!) and that it sleeps without waking overnight?  Mine woke up on its own at 1:00, 4:40, and 8:20 last night (by the way this regular pattern is new, only seen for the last two nights).

Comment: Have you checked to see that the Automatic Maintenance setting is off?  It's under Control Panel > System and Security > Security and Maintenance >  Also, maybe search the event logs to see if there is more information in the event logs as to what turned it on.  You can also try 'powercfg /waketimers' to see it that points you anywhere if you haven't already. 'powercfg /devicequery wake_armed' will tell you what devices can wake it.  May also give a clue.

Comment: I have checked Automatic Maintenance many times and see it's still off today.  I have checked "powercfg /waketimers" many times too, and it used to return nothing, but today shows "ShellExperienceHost.exe" is set even though all wake timers are still disabled in my settings, so this might be a clue.  One internet rumor says I can set CsEnabled=0 to fix this and I think I tried this long ago (I prefer CsEnabled=1 because I do sometimes turn off my display without sleeping...I don't see why disabling "Connected Standby" should be necessary anyway unless there is a bug in play here).

Comment: Glad you are making progress.  Now you just need to track down what event or service is setting that wake timer...   if I recall on of the times I had a fit with it I had to edit some xml files that update orchestrator used but I think I killed those brain cells off because I don’t recall the file. Good luck.  I’m at the end for any more suggestions.  Do post if you find it.

Comment: I don't think I've made progress.  It seems like "whack-a-mole" with Windows changing itself regularly to avoid sleep and get their updates in.  Again, "can you confirm that you have Windows 10 Home (Home edition is important!) and that it sleeps without waking overnight"?

Comment: bobuhito, I have dealt with this issue on Home as well as Pro and Enterprise.  Every time it was a pain in the ass and something different.  I know you don't want to hear it, but until you identify the trigger, keeping it asleep is probably not going to happen.  Just run through one more time: Make sure your NIC's are not set to wake, or wake on special packet, etc.  Make sure any OEM tools for the laptop maker are not loading and running in the background.  Make sure UpdateOrchestrator is dead.  Make sure power config is set to not wake.  Make sure automatic maintenance is not set to wake.

Comment: Make sure you have no streaming apps that offer services that will wake.  Check USB settings if you have anything that can wake it on USB.  Go through event logs looking for anything that woke it up.  Go through all the running and background services and tasks to see if any are set to allow them to wake the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any LAN plugged in to your laptop...magic packets can wake up the PC.
Try this : Open Device Manager > Network Adapters > Right click your LAN adapter eg. "Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller" > Properties> Advanced tab > Property: Wake on Magic Packet, in the dropdown change its value to **Disabled**

Comment: I have not had any ethernet cable plugged in for at least a year.  I also turned off "Power Management" "Allow this device to wake the computer" (for the LAN with almost the same path as you described) at least a year ago.  But, based on your suggestion, I saw that "Shutdown Wake-On-Lan", "Wake on Magic Packet", and "Wake on pattern match" were left enabled, so I disabled them a few days ago to be complete.  For the record, even with that change, my PC is still waking up uncontrollably.

Answer (score 0):

After updating to Windows version 1903 last week and then pausing updates, my computer finally sleeps in, hooray.

So, the answer to my question is yes, but only by pausing updates (which just became possible in version 1903 in May 2019).  To confirm this, I unpaused updates yesterday and sure enough my computer woke itself up once despite disabled "wake timers".  I still consider this ignoring of the "wake timers" setting a bug, but at least I can now pause updates before traveling to avoid the battery dying.

EDIT: Nevermind!  After about a week, my computer started waking up on its own again (with updates still paused, or updates resumed, or paused after resuming to catch up, or...I've also unsuccessfully tried all the standard solutions since then).  It's possible that this is someone else's fault (i.e., my computer's manufacturer, Hewlett Packard), but I believe that waking is Microsoft's intentional decision for the security/updating benefit.  If so, I wish Microsoft would be more transparent about this!