# My Windows 10 computer wakes up by itself from sleep mode

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop, wake-up

I have a newly installed windows 10 computer that wakes up by itself if I have put it in sleep mode.

[image]

When the computer starts up by itself, it will only use the laptop screen (and not my connected display).

It seems to set the keyboard layout to english.

The only way of letting the other display come into play is to shutdown and startup, just restart does not work.

Ok, running commands in an elevated console shows that there is no "wakeup timer" causing this.

```
C:\Windows\System32>powercfg -lastwake
Wake History Count - 0

C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
NONE
```

It do not even have "Allow wake timers" in the advanced power settings mentioned in https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/fixed-windows-10-computer-turns-on-by-itself/ but the dialog is relatively clean.

[image]

I also looked if the mouse was able to wakeup the computer, maybe there are some inaccuracies in the mouse telling the computer that it had been moved. However, the "power management" tab mentioned in https://www.technipages.com/stop-mouse-from-waking-up-windows-10-pc was missing.

[image]

## Docking station

I am using a Lenovo docking station with the computer.

## Trying to setup BIOS

I stumbled on a setting Wake on LAN from Dock.

[image]

But the computer still woke up by itself.
However, it did so with my extra screen in use.

In other words, the problem is not solved yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conclusively stop wake timers from waking Windows 10 desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/973009/conclusively-stop-wake-timers-from-waking-windows-10-desktop)

Answer (score 1):

I am very familiar with powercfg but do not need it for Windows 10 / 11 to sleep properly.

Open Control Panel, Power Options, choose the Balanced Plan.

Now:  Click on Change Advanced Power Settings.

New Power Options window opens (window is in your question). Click on Restore Pan defaults.

Now:

(1) Restart.

(2) Set Power Options to what you wish.  I use Sleep 1 Hour (good battery).

(3) Turn OFF any Hybrid Sleep.

(4) Remove or turn off your mouse.

Put the computer to sleep.  It should now stay asleep.

No issue with Windows 10 X1 4th when I turn the mouse off. No issue with Windows 11 X1 9th when I turn the mouse off and stuff the computer and mouse in my briefcase to move it somewhere.

I find Balanced Plan to be the best general purpose plan.

Comment: I did not find "hybrid sleep" in the settings. Also, it would be great to not have the burden to turn off the mouse  (or remove it) every time I sleep the computer.

Comment: Hybrid Sleep is not on every computer so if not there, no worries.  My mice have a switch on the bottom (Bluetooth) or a USB RF key. I don’t find it too troublesome to remove the USB Key or to turn off the mouse when packing my bag. If suspending in home office I just move the mouse to a still spot  and then suspend. This works fine.

Comment: So if I get you right, the mouse is the problem then?

Comment: Probably, but I keep the mouse still and a bit away from the keyboard and/or turn it off. Yes the mouse can be a problem when the computer has been suspended